# Difference between the lift coefficient of the wing-profile and the wing

Tags: aerodynamics, wing

Let $ c_l $ the wing-profile lift coefficient and $ c_L $ the wing lift coefficient. For small values for the angle of attack $ \alpha $ both coefficients are linearly approximated:
$$ c_l(\alpha)=C_{l_{\alpha}}\cdot (\alpha-\alpha_0)\\[10pt] c_L(\alpha)=C_{L_{\alpha}}\cdot (\alpha-\alpha_0) $$

$ C_{l_{\alpha}} $ is the change of lift coefficient of the wing-profile and $ C_{L_{\alpha}} $ is the change of lift coefficient of the wing and $ \alpha_0 $ describes the angle where the lift is equal to zero. Both values $ C_{l_{\alpha}} $ and $ C_{L_{\alpha}} $ are given in the unit $ \frac{1}{\text{rad}} $. I also know the following relation between these two values given by:
$$ C_{L_{\alpha}}=\frac{C_{l_{\alpha}}}{1+\frac{C_{l_{\alpha}}}{\pi \cdot \Lambda\cdot \tau}} \quad (*)$$ and $ \Lambda $ is the stretch of the wing and $ \tau $ is the wing outline factor.

From here I'm getting confused about the unit's if I look at the formular $(*)$. The value $ C_{l_{\alpha}} $ is given in $ \frac{1}{\text{rad}} $. But in $(*)$ I'm adding the number $1$ with something with the unit $ \frac{1}{\text{rad}} $ which doesn't make sense to me. What went wrong here in the formular $(*)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a practical point of view *rad* can be seen as a dummy unit of measurement, used to signal that angles are *not* measured in degrees.

For example, a circle's circumference is $2\pi r$ and if $r$ is in meters then the circumference is in meters as well and not in rad$\cdot$m. If a platform is rotating at 10rad/s and something stands on the platform at 2 meters from the center, its speed is 10$\cdot$2=20m/s and not 20rad$\cdot$m/s.

As a general rule, stay consistent with units of measurement.

Btw: 1) where did you get that equation? 2) what's $ \Lambda $ the stretch of the wing? 3) And what's $ \tau $ is the wing outline factor?

Comment: Ok. But if I have $ C_{l_\alpha} $ given in $ \frac{1}{\text{rad}} $ is the value $ C_{L_\alpha} $ also already in $ \frac{1}{\text{rad}} $ or should I scale $ C_{l_\alpha} $ scale back to $ \frac{1}{\text{deg}} $ and turn the result $ C_{L_\alpha} $ into $ \frac{1}{\text{rad}} $?

Comment: Everything must be consistent, if the author of that equation says to use 1/rad then 1/rad has to be used. Anyway $C_{l_\alpha}$ should be some 2π with good approximation. Btw where did you get that equation from?

Comment: But which way do I have to choose now? I'm confused. I got that equation from my lesson.

Comment: I don't understand now what's the matter... In the equation $C_{l_\alpha}$ has to be in 1/rad i.e. the angles **not** in degrees. What's the "*stretch of the wing*"?

Comment: "In the equation Clα has to be in 1/rad i.e". But is the result also in 1/rad? $ \Lambda=\frac{b^2}{S} $ and b is the wingspan and S the surface of the projected wing area.

Comment: The results is in 1/rad as well unless otherwise noted. Ah ok, the aspect ratio, never heard of stretch of the wing.

Comment: Re "Rad is not a real unit of measurement," -- sure it is-- approx  equal to 57.3 degrees.  There's a valid counter-argument to the logic of your second paragraph, but this isn't math s.e., so I won't go to deeply into that --

Comment: @quietflyer: yes I know, anyway thanks for saving us the related math :D

Comment: But math is beautiful. :D ;)

Comment: That's true ;) Anyway wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer to give all people around the world the possibility to give an answer 

Comment: @sophit: I don't understand what are you meaning by that.